# Рефлексия.Атрибуты

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Man man = new Man("Anton", 30, "Blue");
            Cat cat = new Cat("Мяу", "White", 5);

            Console.WriteLine("Свойства объекта " + man.GetType() + " :");
            ColorProperty.ColorPrint(man);
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Свойства объекта " + cat.GetType() + " :");
            ColorProperty.ColorPrint(cat);
        }
    }
    class Man
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        private int Age;
        [ColorProperty(ConsoleColor.Blue)]
        public string Eyes { get; set; }
        public Man(string name, int age, string color)
      {
         Name = name;
         Age = age;
         Eyes = color;
      }

    }
    class Cat
    {
        [ColorProperty(ConsoleColor.Yellow)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [ColorProperty(ConsoleColor.Red)]
        public string Color { get; set; }
        private int Age;
        public Cat(string name, string color, int age)
      {
         Name = name;
         Color = color;
         Age = age;

      }
    }
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    class ColorPropertyAttribute : System.Attribute
    {
        public ColorPropertyAttribute(ConsoleColor color)
        {
            Color = color;
        }

        public ConsoleColor Color { get; private set; }
    }
    class ColorProperty
    {
        public static void ColorPrint(object obj)
        {
            Type t = obj.GetType();
            object[] p = t.GetProperties();

            foreach (object pr in p)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(pr);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Здравствуйте!Как в данном коде вывести все значения свойств, и покрасить их в цвета согласно примененным атрибутам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, как-то так:

```
public static void ColorPrint(object obj)
{
    PropertyInfo[] props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
    ConsoleColor oldColor = Console.ForegroundColor;

    foreach (var pinfo in props)
    {
        ColorPropertyAttribute colorAttr =
            pinfo.GetCustomAttribute<ColorPropertyAttribute>();
        if (colorAttr != null)
            Console.ForegroundColor = colorAttr.Color;

        object propValue = pinfo.GetValue(obj);
        Console.WriteLine(propValue);

        if (colorAttr != null)
            Console.ForegroundColor = oldColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: а почему бы _Console.ForegroundColor = oldColor;_ за цикл не вынести?

Comment: @Grundy: Потому что возможны свойства без атрибута, и они должны отображаться цветом по умолчанию.

Comment: а, все. понял:)